# Why high quality broadcast studio monitors use a middle range AB amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio

I had an issue with my Genelec 8010A studio monitors. Until recently I was truly happy with these monitors. The sound quality is exceptional, pure, precise the dynamic is impressive even though you need a subwoofer to have a better cover the low frequencies.

Anyway, one of my speaker stopped working few days ago and I decided to take a deep  look. The active monitor is based on a embedded TDA7269A (AB, 2x14W, 0.03..0.7% THD). I am not an expert in audio electronics, but I am a bit surprised that such products use a very middle range integrated amplifier.

Is this something surprising. I would like to get an "engineering rationale" for this kind of technical choices.

Comment: Most likely it is good enough. Can you hear any problems in the produced audio?

Comment: Engineering rationale is not audiophool rational. If a human can't hear the difference between 2$ mid range AB amplifier and a top end 10$ amplifier, guess which one will be used?

Comment: It's not a great amplifier. My Mackie studio monitors use TDA7293 amplifiers (also class AB) but have a distortion level of 0.1% at 50 watts output 20 Hz to 15 kHz. The TDA7269 is rated at about 1% distortion with 5 watts output from 100 Hz to 15 kHz. Barely the same ballpark.

Comment: Part of an engineer's job is to be able to calculate as precisely as possible what is needed to meet spec, because not every product is designed to be the finest of it's type.  There exist engineers who mostly use their skills to make their designs as close to perfect as possible, but usually the goal is closer to "as good as it can be for what it is" and "exactly as good as it has to be" and large safety margins are mostly seen where life safety is involved or as incidental side effects of a part that was necessary for another reason.

Comment: So your parts and methods (most significant costs) are based on "exactly as good as it has to be" to meet spec (the specification including necessary distortion/error rate/reliability after x years, etc).  And the use of those parts (less significant costs) would be determined by "as good as it can be for what it is".  Due to market factors, overorders, surplusses, that sort of thing, occasionally you'd see a bit of "as good as it can be for what it is" on the part selection side.

Comment: What is a good design? Brilliant hardware design has either been doing more with for the same (cost, PCB space) or doing the same for less. The biggest problem with engineering is over designing - so the fact they have been able to do that with an AB really proves their great design. The best design meets the specification and no better unless you can do either of the things above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor speakers are made like any other product, and therefore made to cater for a certain type of customers. Monitor speakers are a bit of a niche market, which means that the manufacturer has to maximise the amount of profit on the amount the customers are willing to pay for.

The engineer's job is to make the best product possible for the lowest cost, and here is where compromised come into play. In this case the lowest cost is defined by how much the sales department allows you to spend.
This budget will define the components that can be used in this product, so if the best transducers that can be fitted into the monitor have a distortion of, let's say 1%, there is no point in selecting an amplifier that has a distortion of 0.1%. In the same way selecting an A class amplifier, will require a much larger power supply which will eat into the already small budget.

It is all down to compromises, and the engineer's job is to design the best product that a limited amount of money can buy.

An experienced engineer will also choose the components in a way that speakers will have a frequency response that is as linear as possible to the human ear, and therefore compensating for any of the flaws of the other parts in the system.

Answer (score -3):

A/B amplifiers are very efficient, so they're popular in powered monitors both for being able to physically fit inside and for a low cooling requirement. Class D has some advantages, like increased efficiency, but the pro audio world is somewhat conservative in its design, and D amps have a lot of electromagnetic interference that could ruin a monitor for active listening.

You like your Genelec monitors so much because the woofer, tweeter, amplifier, and crossover were all designed and chosen to match one another. The engineers probably tested dozens to hundreds of amplifiers and chose that one for how well it paired with the speaker they wanted to use.

Comment: What's *active listening*?  Wikipedia says: "Active listening is a technique that is used in counseling, training, and solving disputes or conflicts"

Comment: I'm talking about the audio engineering term: https://makingmusic.ableton.com/active-listening

Comment: How would "electromagnetic interference" affect an amplifier's use for any form of listening, active or otherwise? Humans are not affected by EMI.

Comment: @duskwuff electronic circuits are affected by EMI.

Comment: …right, but what are you trying to imply here? That class D amplifiers all exhibit some form of distortion which is perceptible to humans?

Comment: @duskwuff Yes, that is what I'm saying. All amplifiers regardless of type have distortion present. I'd recommend reading Yamaha's Sound Reinforcement Handbook to get a background on audio electronics.

Comment: @PascLeRasc please edit your answer to incorporate some of these comments (e.g., "active listening"). Your comment on class-D amplifiers seems like a non-sequitur, but it could be incorporated in a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @EdgarBrown No thank you, I think my answer is clear enough.